# Special characters are printed only as a part of string, but not independently (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, utf

I work with strings containing diacritics. When I print the string, it is printed correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = "ˈtau̯rum"
print(s)
> ˈtau̯rum
```

However, When I iterate over the string and print each character independently, some of the characters are not printed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = "ˈtau̯rum"
for c in s:

    print (c)

>
ˈ
t
a
u

r
u
m
```

Comment: It's a COMBINING character. It probably has no meaning for your terminal unless *combined* with a preceding character. Your terminal is already treating it weirdly from the looks of it.

Comment: I am less concerned of the output printed in the terminal, but how can I make sure these characters are represented properly internally, e.g. when I manipulate these strings in my program?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggested, the printing issue is most likely due to how your terminal handles displaying the unicode characters. You can check that the character is what you expect by encoding it to `utf-8` bytes, or by using the [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) built-in.

> Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of that character. For example, ord('a') returns the integer 97 and ord('€') (Euro sign) returns 8364. This is the inverse of [chr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr).

E.g.

```
Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 23 2018, 19:19:42)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.1.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

IIn [1]: s = "ˈtau̯rum"                                                                                                 

In [2]: print(s)
ˈtau̯rum

In [3]: for c in s:
   ...:     print(c, c.encode('utf-8'), ord(c))
   ...:
ˈ b'\xcb\x88' 712
t b't' 116
a b'a' 97
u b'u' 117
̯  b'\xcc\xaf' 815
r b'r' 114
u b'u' 117
m b'm' 109
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
import unicodedata
s = "ˈtau̯rum" 

a = ""
for c in s:
    if unicodedata.combining(c):
        a += c
    else:
        print(a)
        a = c
else:
    print(a)
```

In this manner, you are combining the combining characters. You may substitute `print(a)` to a list storage of codepoint that must be keep together.